# The end user has not completed Auth & Auth sign in flow eBay

Tags: php, codeigniter, ebay-api

I'm trying to fetching tokens from Trading → Get session ID, Trading → Fetch token, but after providing session id to Fetch token it says:

> The end user has not completed Auth & Auth sign in flow.

The error is as follows:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
[Timestamp] => 2018-05-29T10:21:13.879Z
[Ack] => Failure
[Errors] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [ShortMessage] => The end user has not completed Auth & Auth sign in flow.
        [LongMessage] => The end user has not completed Auth & Auth sign in flow.
        [ErrorCode] => 21916017
        [SeverityCode] => Error
        [ErrorClassification] => RequestError
    )

[Version] => 1057
[Build] => E1057_CORE_API_18682351_R1
)
```

I'm using the code for fetch token as below:

```
$requestXmlBody = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>';
$requestXmlBody .= '<GetSessionIDRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">';
$requestXmlBody .= "<RequesterCredentials><eBayAuthToken>".$code."</eBayAuthToken></RequesterCredentials>";
$requestXmlBody .= "<ErrorLanguage>en_US</ErrorLanguage>";
$requestXmlBody .= "<WarningLevel>High</WarningLevel>";
$requestXmlBody .= "<RuName>".$ruName."</RuName>";
$requestXmlBody .= '</GetSessionIDRequest>';
$session = new Ebaysession($code, $devID, $appID, $certID, $server_url, 967, $siteID, $verb);

$responseXml = $session->sendHttpRequest($requestXmlBody);
```

I already got SessionID successfully and I'm using that SessionId to FetchTokens. But it's not working anymore.

I'm using this URL for login: `https://signin.sandbox.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?SignIn&runame='.$ruName.'&SessID='.$sessionID`.